# How much of Surah Al-Baqarah need to be recited for protection of the household?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I came across this hadith before:

> Abu Hurayrah reports that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w.) said: “Do not make your houses like graves, for the Shaytan runs away from a house in which Surat al-Baqarah is recited” (narrated by [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/252), 780).

Does this imply that *all* or Surah Baqarah needs to be recited, a set amount or a specific ayat from it?

Comment: Surat al-Baqarah - implying all of it.  The hadith isn't authentic though because Suhail is da'if and he reports it unclear from his father, Abu Saalih.

Comment: @sayyid From what I found its from Muslim though.

Comment: It's in Muslim, the reporter Suhail was accepted by Muslim but rejected by others; and he's the only one who reported this narrative.   It's up to you.

Comment: The hadith can also be found in Jami' at-Tirmdihi http://sunnah.com/urn/731120 with a similar wording and a slightly different sanad!